# Electro magnetic interferences (EMI) generated by power circuit reset low voltage integrated circuits (ICs)

Tags: relay, emc, filtering

The main question here is (explanation will follow):
Is there a way to filter out low voltage oscillations (>10MHz) on pins that have to stay high for the system to function? Oscillations are induced by EMI emitted by power circuit during relay bouncing). RC filters 100Ohm/100nF did not work. Traces are ~50cm long.

[Explanation]:

I'm currently struggling with proper EMI filtering for the low voltage control circuit that is responsible for switching on/off high voltage capacitors using relays.

I realize that the low level part of the circuit has a bunch of design flaws (e.g. the logic signal between uC and shift-reg could've been arranged into a differential pair). But currently I'm trying to figure out a way to modify the circuit with as little PCB modifications as possible.

Here is the essential part of the setup:
[image]

Power circuit is operating on fairly high voltage and current, but I don't care about the quality of power of this circuit, **moreover I cannot modify it**.

The only issue I have to deal with looks like this (the description will follow):

[image]

- Yellow - Power circuit voltage
- Blue - Power circuit current
- Green - logic signal (EN or CLR, see schematics)

Green signal represents EN or CLR; it is a CMOS 3.3V open-drain pin. When voltage falls below certain treshold (I guess 1.8V) it is no longer high, therefore the shift-reg resets. It cannot reset.

Comment: What values and types of bypass capacitors are used on the 3.3v power right at the µC?

Comment: is the shift_reg and the uC on the same ground and is the actual power loop associated with teh 24V relay going nowhere near the uP

Comment: Do you really mean 50 cm traces?

Comment: What are the logic lines doing at this point...are they acting to cause relays to switch, and when and which relays are switching?  Flyback diodes (reverse biased wrt 24V and parallel to relay coils) would greatly improve reliability as well as EMI issues.

Comment: @JonRB power circuit, 24V and 5V all have electrically separated power sources, 24V and 5V have common ground connected through 150nH inductor.

Comment: @Cristobol Relays are switched according to control algorithm, logic lines are for controlling operation of shift register; simplistic approach for now - voltage level on both of them cannot fall below logic high threshold. Flyback diodes are installed, not mentioned here as this diode helps reducing overvoltage on relay's coil, the disturbance, however, is generated by high power side, specifically, switching on a charged capacitor. This influences 3.3V logic lines.

Comment: @David Unfortunately yup... I only want to make it work for now, redesign is coming up.

Comment: @rdtsc uC is placed on a development board i.e. it is properly filtered from power supply point. Shift registers have a set of electrolytic and ceramic caps on power lines. No disturbances were observed on power lines. 100nF/36V ceramics on the schematics are a simple passive filter though - this was a rough calculation for cutoff frequency way below 10MHz, I'm not sure of resonant frequency or ESR.